# Titanium: animate view back and forth (return to original position)

Tags: android, ios, animation, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm working on a simple Alloy app. I have a view I want to move back and forth horizontally (thus to move and then return to its original position).

I wrote this function

```
function move(view) {

  var origin = view.getCenter();

  console.log("origin ", origin);
  console.log("rect ", view.getRect());

  var forth = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
  forth.duration = 700;
  forth.center = {
    x: 0
  };
  forth.addEventListener('complete', function() {
    view.animate(back);
  });

  var back = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
  back.duration = 300;
  back.center = {
    x: origin.x
  };
  back.addEventListener('complete', function() {
    alert('completed');
  });

  view.animate(forth);
}
```

I you run it, it crashes at `x: origin.x` because `origin` is undefined. Moreover, both `view.center` and `view.rect` are undefined, thus it's impossible for me to store the original position.

Any help?

Thanks

PS: Code has been tested on iOS simulator, although is meant to be Android and iOS compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just animate the left position and work with the view.getRect() ?

```js
var origin = view.getRect();

//console.log("origin ", origin);
console.log("rect ", view.getRect());

var forth = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
forth.duration = 5000;
forth.left = 0;

forth.addEventListener('complete', function() {
   view.animate(back);
});

var back = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
back.duration = 5000;
back.left = origin.x;


back.addEventListener('complete', function() {
  alert('completed');
});

view.animate(forth);
```